# Switch between two excel workbooks by a macro shortcut

Tags: excel, vba

I need to be able to witch between two excel workbooks by a macro shortcut - do I need a third workbook for this - also can I have a macro which will close an open workbook with a certain name?
Dave

Comment: maybe try ctrl+tab.

Comment: thanks - what if I have 5 workbooks and I need to switch to specific one?

Answer (score 0):

Excel have a build in function to allow to to switch workbooks faster. Please see the article below to enable this:

[Switch wookbooks faster](https://excelsemipro.com/2010/10/switch-between-workbooks-faster-in-excel-2007-and-2010/)

Using this enables you to select the specific workbook you want to switch to.

Comment: You could even combine the record macro option to record clicking this if you really do need a macro.